# Remove %2523 from url and redirect to new, without that using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I don't have an idea how can I remove %2523 from URL made by GET in php. I want to redirect users to page without that. Sometimes it has # on string beggining, and that's why it generates that "%2523".

For example, want to redirect them from something like:

> localhost/catalog/value/%2523string

to

> localhost/catalog/value/string

My current .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/catalog/value\.php\?value=([^/]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /catalog/value/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^catalog/([^/]*)$ /value/value.php?color=$1 [L]
```

Hopefully you can help me with that, trying from yesterday and still didn't nothing works.

Comment: `%2523string`  normally due to spaces on your url... make sure you remove spaces on your get

Comment: thanks for quick reply. it hasn't spaces, this generate probably because of #, which begins a string.

Comment: `header("Location: ".str_replace('%2523', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));`

Comment: Wow, didn't think about this. But... Is it SEO friendly? Btw. my Chrome shows an error after that - "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved that by adding this at the .htaccess beggining:

```
RewriteRule ^([^%]*)\%23(.*)$ /catalog/value/$2 [R=301,L]
```